# Accessing main form from timer event

Tags: c#, winforms

I am creating a

```
System.Timers.Timer aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
```

and want to access the main form, or Form1 from the

```
private static void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {...}
```

event, how do I do this?  I can't find an example online, via google, that does this.  I am drawing some graphics and want to change them when the timer event fires.  I can't use the form timer as I want to port this code to something else and it won't be available.

Thanks

Comment: Where is the timer located with respect to Form1, and what exactly do you mean by "access the main form". Do you not know how create and enable the timer, or do you not know how to instantiate the object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't like the following code very much, but if you cannot find another way of getting a reference to your `Form1` instance into the event handler, you could try it via [`Application.OpenForms`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.forms.application.openforms.aspx):

```
// using System.Linq;
// using System.Windows.Forms; 

Form1 mainForm = Application.OpenForms.OfType<Form1>().SingleOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is how to access a method from the Form1 in timer, but it is in a separate class, then what you could do is a pass a reference of Form1 to the class that contains the timer. Declare a variable in the classes scope :

```
Form1 mainForm;
```

It is important you do not instantiate it here. Then create a method like this :

```
public void PassReference(Form1 form1)
{
   this.mainForm = form1;
}
```

Now, after you call PassReference from MainForm you will have access to all public methods in Form1.

Answer (score 0):

I hope timer is also in the MainForm. In that case you can use 'this'.

`this` - is MainForm

Answer (score 0):

Your event is declared as static but the time itself is not.

If you must have a static event, keep a static reference to your form as well and use that reference from within your timers event.